# Jersey client gives me different result than other client.

Tags: java, http, jersey-client

I am working on a Geometry Dash API for Java. I am using WireShark to find out how should some requests look like and then try to do some requests using [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restlet-client-rest-api-t/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm), then I write a some java code doing the request and parsing the response. But there's a request, that works inside the [restlet client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/restlet-client-rest-api-t/aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm): [image]

So I am getting:

```
1:TheRealC05:2:42854106:13:77:17:52:10:17:11:12:3:1051:46:1467:4:23:8:0:18:1:19:0:50:0:20::21:129:22:51:23:30:24:32:25:1:26:18:28:1:43:14:48:1:30:0:16:7450834:31:0:44::45::49:0:29:1
```

But doesn't work with Jersey client:

```
final Form form = new Form();
form.param("secret", getSecret());
form.param("gameVersion", "21");
form.param("binaryVersion", "34");
form.param("targetAccountID", "7450834");
final String text = this.httpClient.target(getDatabase()
        .path("/getGJUserInfo20.php")).request()
        .buildPost(Entity.entity(form, MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE))
        .invoke(String.class);
```

Here I am getting `-1`.

#### So what is the difference between those two requests?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, that I was extending path to the database, so the method got wrong database url.